# Increased memory use when moving game pieces

Tags: vb.net, memory, bitmap

I'm currently developing my coursework for my A-level computer science. And for my coursework, I have tasked myself to design Shogi (Japanese Chess) in Visual Basic. I've programmed each pieces movements, loading each pieces bitmaps, how to move a piece and quite a few other things.

The game works but I noticed a problem. Every time I move a piece, whether that be a pawn, king or whatever, the memory usage increases by around 7MB. 7MB is round about the size of all the bitmaps I am using, added together.
I can understand where this memory usage increase is occurring. I have provided some snippets of my code for the purpose of understanding:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Text = "Shogi"
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.Size = New Point(1280, 750)

    pb = New PictureBox() With {
        .Parent = Me,
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        .BackColor = Color.Green
    }

    Shogi_SetUp()
    board_refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub board_refresh()
    surface = New Bitmap(Me.Size.Width, Me.Size.Height)
    device = Graphics.FromImage(surface)

    Dim Board_Design As New Drawing.Bitmap(1280, 720)
    Board_Design = New Bitmap("BackGround_WIP.bmp")
    device.DrawImage(Board_Design, 0, 0, 1280, 720)

    Dim move_btn As New Drawing.Bitmap(128, 32)
    Dim move_btn_TF As Boolean = False
    If move_btn_TF = False Then
        move_btn = New Bitmap("Movement_Button.bmp")
    ElseIf move_btn_TF = True Then
        move_btn = New Bitmap("Movement_Button.bmp")
    End If
    device.DrawImage(move_btn, 980, 564, 128, 32)
    Doupdate()
    pb.Image = surface
End Sub
```

The lines below will repeat but for every single piece, placing them individually on the board.

`digital_board` and `expanded_board` are 2d-arrays. `digital_board` is filled with numbers, each number assigned to a certain piece. For instance, 1 would be king, 2 would be queen. `expanded_board` is filled with numbers but this time, the numbers are both negative and positive and are assigned to only one piece instead of the same type of pieces. For instance, they'll be 41 for rook 1 and 42 for rook two.

```
Private Sub Doupdate()
    Dim doupdate_code As Integer = 0
    For y = 0 To 9
        For x = 0 To 9
            If Digital_board(x, y) = 1 Or Digital_board(x, y) = -1 Then
                If Expanded_board(x, y) = 10 Then
                    Try
                        N_Gyoku = New Bitmap("Gyoku_Bitmap.bmp")
                        N_Gyoku.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)
                        device.DrawImage(N_Gyoku, Default_X + (x * 68), Default_Y + (y * 68), 64, 64)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show("Error code: N_Gyoku - DoUpdate(001)")
                    End Try
                ElseIf Expanded_board(x, y) = -10 Then
                    Try
                        S_Gyoku = New Bitmap("Gyoku_Bitmap.bmp")
                        device.DrawImage(S_Gyoku, Default_X + (x * 68), Default_Y + (y * 68), 64, 64)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show("Error code: S_Gyoku - DoUpdate(001)")
                    End Try
                End If
        Next
    Next

Private Sub Piece_Selected(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pb.Click, pb.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        If piece_Selected_int = 0 Or piece_Selected_TF = True Then
            For y = 0 To 9
                For x = 0 To 9
                    If (Default_X + (68 * x)) < e.X And e.X < ((Default_X + 608) - (68 * (8 - x))) And (Default_Y + (68 * y)) < e.Y And e.Y < ((Default_Y + 608) - (68 * (8 - y))) Then
                        If piece_Selected_TF = False Then
                            Dim value_digital_board As Integer = Digital_board(x, y)
                            Select Case value_digital_board
                                Case = 1, -1
                                    MessageBox.Show("Gyoku Selected")
                                    piece_Selected_int = 1
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 2, -2
                                    MessageBox.Show("Kin-Sho Selected")
                                    piece_Selected_int = 2
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 3, -3
                                    MessageBox.Show("Gin-Sho Selected")
                                    piece_Selected_int = 3
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 4, -4
                                    MessageBox.Show("Kei-Ma Selected")
                                    piece_Selected_int = 4
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 5, -5
                                    piece_Selected_int = 5
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 6, -6
                                    piece_Selected_int = 6
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 7, -7
                                    piece_Selected_int = 7
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 8, -8
                                    piece_Selected_int = 8
                                    ox = x
                                    oy = y
                                Case = 0
                            End Select
                        ElseIf piece_Selected_TF = True Then
                            Select Case piece_Selected_int
                                Case = 1
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Gyoku moved")
                                    Gyoku_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 2
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Kin-Sho moved")
                                    KinSho_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 3
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Gin-Sho moved")
                                    GinSho_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 4
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Kei-Ma moved")
                                    KeiMa_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 5
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Kyo-Sha moved")
                                    KyoSha_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 6
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Kaku moved")
                                    Kaku_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 7
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Hisha moved")
                                    Hisha_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                                Case = 8
                                    piece_Selected_int = 0
                                    piece_Selected_TF = False
                                    MessageBox.Show("Fuhyo moved")
                                    Fuhyo_Movement(ox, oy, x, y)
                                    dispose_update()
                                    board_refresh()
                            End Select
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        ElseIf piece_Selected_int > 0 Then
            If 980 < e.X And e.X < 1108 And 564 < e.Y And e.Y < 596 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Button clicked")
                piece_Selected_TF = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me find a way to stop my game from using more memory every time I move a piece?

Comment: Not sure what "mememory incrimination" is, but you are creating **lots** of new Bitmaps and not disposing of any of them.  Anything and everything which implements the `Dispose` method needs to be disposed of when you are done with it.  Often you'd want to use such things in a  `Using` block.  So, your app is leaking.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your `Doupdate` Sub seems to be missing an `End Sub` as well as an `End If`. I didn't add them when I edited your post as I don't know if there are other statements missing as well.